# What is the most integrated Drupal 7 shopping cart for CiviCRM?

Tags: drupal, ubercart, commerce

We want to have a shop that sells tshirts, mugs, etc. We want people to have an option of logging into CiviCRM at check-out, and to be able to view their shop orders through CiviCRM.

I see there is Commerce CiviCRM and UC CiviCRM and am trying to decide which is the better option. Features we care about are:

- Futureproof: which will have more longterm updates & support?
- Easy to set up and use: we are new to CiviCRM
- Best integration with CiviCRM: does one have more features than the other?

Any help/advice is appreciated.

Update: Thanks to everyone who responded, it looks like Commerce is the way to go.

Answer (score 5):

yes Eileen at Fuzion is working towards pulling together Commerce + CiviEntities + Rules as a more flexible approach. We have clients using both Commerce_CiviCRM and uc_civicrm and have had some grief with both of them, such as in terms of when should it update civi addresses and when shouldn't it and clients wanting different outcomes etc. Or eg can customer buy a Membership as part of the cart and get instant member discount on other items in the cart. Hence us going for a more flexible solution.
But to more directly answer your question, starting now I would go down the  Commerce path.

Comment: I agree but Commerce definitely has a much larger learning curve.  Much more flexible, but dang, it seems like I have to relearn it any time we set something up.

Answer (score 3):

I'll be launching a CiviCRM 4.6 instance with Commerce integration in the next two months.  I spoke with Eileen, who brought the existing integration current with 4.4 - she said that if she was starting today, she'd just make a Drupal Feature that used the `civicrm_entity` and `rules` modules.  I'm not sure if this is the route I'll be taking, or updating the existing extension.

Sorry this is only a partial answer - but if it helps, we know we'll be maintaining a solution that uses Commerce for a while.

Comment: jon. anything worth updating regarding your post above?

Comment: Honestly I don't even remember who this client was!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Jon G and @peternz have said about integrations and Eileen's work, it's also worth considering the future of the Drupal modules themselves. The consensus in comparisons between them seems to be that Commerce's architecture makes it more future proof that Ubercart's.

Comment: agreed - though UC did not succumb as quicly as punters picked when Commerce came out

Comment: Yes. Commerce took a long time to build out features, and UC didn't roll over.

Answer (score 1):

The extra rules we use for this are in this module

https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/commerce_civicrm_rules

Comment: Begging your pardon, but since [link-only answers are frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231), any chance you could summarize what is available at the destination?

Comment: Is the module reference above usable in a production environment?