# Suggested Approach for Cart style donations (Donation Pages) for Crowdfunding P2P site

Tags: civicontribute, webform-civicrm, contribution-page, civicrm-entity, commerce

**My Question is: For the current 4.6.4 CiviCRM are there any suggested solutions / recipies to create a crowdfunding / P2P site with shopping cart style options ?**  Also, please comment if this is something you are interested in building/funding/etc.

**Goal: Build a P2P Crowdsourcing Application that integrates with CiviCRM**
Crowdfunding / Peer2Peer social campaings have been very popular and effective.  Civi has critical pieces to running a crowdsorucing platform but an important part is to select multiple causes and add to a cart.
Some great sites out there are:

- Razoo
- CauseVox
- Indiegogo
- Fundly
- Classy
- FirstGiving
- Justgive
- And many many more of all shapes/sizes (I have some lists if anyone needs one.)

I found some 3rd party services that (claim) to integrate with CiviCRM (I'm open to using a 3rd party but these seem to provide data and not workflow integration.):

- justgiving.com
- flipcause.com

CiviCRM is really well suited to provide many "causes" and integrate back-end workflow.  For example, **each of the causes being a donation page and leverage the p2p are personal campaign pages.**

I'm working with an organization that wants to integrate Civi workflow and allow the following:

```
1. Create a Grant Application (ie. A Cause)
2. When Grant is approved generate a donation page
3. Populate the donation page with a story and info from the Grant
4. Display pages in CMS
5. Checkout / payment via donation page in CiviCRM.
```

Most of this is nicely built-in to CiviCRM but there are a couple of issues:

1. Checkout is for a single donation page, but want the opportunity to "Shop" for multiple in one checkout. (major)
2. We could be looking at 100s of donation pages which may get tricky to manage without some hierarchy in the backend(minor)
3. Custom relationship between grant and donation page (minor)

There are several solutions for Civicrm [Events with built-in shopping cart logic](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/CiviEvent+Cart+Checkout) and a [new Order API](http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRM/Order+API).  There are other modules / extensions that require a shopping cart:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_civicrm    Druplal Ubercart has a shaky future - Commerce has the limelight
- https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce_civicrm  Not maintained - older version support
- Webform Civicrm is another option, but it only supports one static donation page.

More discussions here:

- http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=32376.0
- http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=29879.0
- [What is the most integrated Drupal 7 shopping cart for CiviCRM?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2640/what-is-the-most-integrated-drupal-7-shopping-cart-for-civicrm)

Answer (score 2):

I think Commerce is still your best option. We have moved away from using the module and instead are building Commerce solutions using the Civi Rules module. That way we get full 'cart' features as provided by Commerce and its many contrib modules, plus the integration required for sych'ing contacts etc.

Comment: That means completely bypassing the civicrm donation workflow, payment, pcp, tell-a-friend, etc. and doing everything in drupal - right?  couldn't even use webform-civicrm I imagine. I'm not saying that is a bad idea, but seems like there is so much already in civicrm to use for this ...

Comment: Not sure how much i can answer in a comment. If you want to ping me on skype sometime I can try and give you a run through, but eg the Contributions also get recorded in civicrm, hence you can still use Scheduled Reminders off that 'trigger'. But agree that if you are using PCP and Tell a Friend then there would be some work to accommodate that via Rules etc.